# Bcrypt invalid ELF header on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have deployed my application to herokuapp. So when I tried to call the API which I have just built, it returns error. Error as below:

```
2018-05-19T06:51:35.980033+00:00 app[web.1]:   return process.dlopen(module, path._makeLong(filename));
2018-05-19T06:51:35.980014+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:681
2018-05-19T06:51:35.980037+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-05-19T06:51:35.980035+00:00 app[web.1]:                  ^
2018-05-19T06:51:35.980042+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
2018-05-19T06:51:35.980038+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: /app/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node: invalid ELF header
```

My code works fine when I ran it on my local machine but it does not work once it is deployed to heroku. How can I solve this ? I have tried searching all over online but could not find any solution to this.

Comment: You didn't happen to check in the `node_modules` directory to your git repository, did you...? That's what it seems like you've done. Don't do that.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Unfortunately, I did. How can I fix this ? I am kinda new to this.

Comment: Please stop reposting this question. You have been told the same thing over and over as the cause of the issue is that "binary" content from your machine is being uploaded to heroku instead of "building" the `node_modules` there.